# How to write a data to file each in separate line?

Tags: c++, file, io, fstream

I would like to write to file data each in separate line. The code is show below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void writeToFile(const vector<double> &data){
    ofstream outFile("newData.txt", std::ofstream::binary);
    double num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 4;
    for (const auto &it : data) {
        outFile << it << endl;
    }
    outFile.close();
}
int main(){
    vector<double> data { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    writeToFile(data);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the "newData.txt" file is:

```
123
```

I would like to get:

```
1
2
3
```

I use endl, but it doesn't work. Have you some idea how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: What are you talking about? After running this file, it would create a new with each number on a new line.

Comment: What compiler do you use? I run it in visual studia 2013 and it works as I said...

Comment: You are writing ASCII text to a file, so why would you use binary?

Comment: Ok, now I know I need to delete "std::ofstream::binary". Thanks.

Comment: I think it might actually depend on what text editor you use to open newData.txt.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `std::ofstream::binary` for text files. Open as:

```
ofstream outFile("newData.txt", std::ofstream::out);
```

or equivalently just:

```
ofstream outfile("newData.txt");
```

Comment: @user3603858 Not using it?

Comment: Edited with my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are opening the file in binary mode. Try ofstream outFile("new.txt"), this will open the file in text mode and endl should now write numbers in separate line.